# Unable to run Appium server

Tags: ios, ruby, testing, automation, appium

I'm fairly new to automation testing and thought I'd give appium a try. I'm trying to run a test script in ruby however I keep getting the same error

```
Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/appium_lib-3.0.3/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:437:in    rescue in start_driver': ERROR: Unable to connect to Appium. Is the server running?(RuntimeError)from Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby2.1.2/gems/appium_lib-.0.3/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:424:in `start_driver'from   Appiumtest.rb:11:in<main>
```

When I enter the server address 127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub on my browser I get

```
That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource
```

Here is my ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'
capabilities = {
        'appium-version' =>'1.0',
        'platformName'=> 'iOS',
        'platformVersion'=> '7.1',
}

server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"

Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities).start_driver
Appium.promote_appium_methods Object

find_element(:xpath,  "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[4]").click
driver_quit
```

Any pointers on this will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the adress `127.0.0.1:4725` at the Appium Server preferences as well?
Standard is `0.0.0.0:4723` there, so that might be the issue.

Furthermore, you might change the path to `server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub/"`